# What is the purpose of "fieldName" in Lucene MoreLikeThis.like(fieldName, reader)?

Tags: java, lucene, morelikethis

I was trying to "upgrade" [this MoreLikeThis example](http://doduck.com/lucene-morelikethis-java-example/) to Lucene 5.2.1. I was able to make it run, but I don't understand the purpose of the argument `fieldName` of the method `like(String fieldName, Reader... readers)`.

The documents were created and indexed as

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new StringField("id", id, Store.YES));
doc.add(new Field("title", title, type));
doc.add(new Field("content", content, type));
```

The query was initialized as follows

```
MoreLikeThis mlt = new MoreLikeThis(reader);
mlt.setFieldNames(new String[] { "title", "content" });
Reader sReader = new StringReader(searchForSimilar);
Query query = mlt.like("title", sReader);
```

As I said, it worked as expected. Similar docs were properly recovered and ranked. So, since de API doesn't explain the argument, I did some experiments: instead "title", I changed it to "content", "xxx" and NULL.

All of them returned the same documents, with the same score...

I tried to look inside Lucene source, the argument is used to call `addTermFrequencies`, and then `analyzer.tokenStream(fieldName, r)`. After that the code become to complex to my knowledge...

So, the argument seems be "important", but as I told, it made no difference.

Does anyone knows its purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just for the analyzer.

In order to query effectively, MLT needs to know how to tokenize your content.  Calls to `Analyzer.tokenStream` must be passed a fieldname, because some analyzers need it.

Many don't though.  `StandardAnalyzer`, for instance, does not use that parameter (take a look at `StandardAnalyzer.createComponents`, and you'll see it never actually does anything with it).  For `StandardAnalyzer`, and indeed most analyzers, in my experience, that argument could be anything.  The field doesn't even have to exist.

An example of one that *does* use it, is [PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper.html).  If you were using that, it would need to know the fieldname to determine which analysis method to use.

As far as I know, it isn't used for anything else.  `like(int docnum)` does not require a fieldname because it drives off of the indexed term vectors directly, which are already analyzed.